# How to set diffrent plugin options with webpack-merge

Tags: javascript, webpack

base https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

I want to use diffrent html template in *webpack.dev.js* & *webpack.prod.js*

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Production'
        }),
    ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./public/index-dev.html',
        })
    ]
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    plugins: 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./public/index.html',
        })
    ]
});
```

report *ReferenceError: HtmlWebpackPlugin is not defined* when *npm run* with these config

Comment: Did you import the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` class from `html-webpack-plugin` package in `webpack.dev.js` and `webpack.prod.js` files?

Comment: HtmlWebpackPlugin in webpack.common.js, I don't know how to call it in webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js  @slideshowp2

Comment: With out an explicit require/import you cann't directly access HtmlWebpackPlugin of anything else from one config file in another. Merge only joins the config portion not the whole files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out an explicit require/import you cann't directly access HtmlWebpackPlugin of anything else from one config file in another. Merge only joins the config portion not the whole files.

Therefor you must have `const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');` in all files where HtmlWebpackPlugin is used.

webpage-merge is does not merge all file data just the module.exports object itself.